# Snowflake check if Schema exists

Tags: matillion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake doesn't accept T-sql but i'm trying to Create schema If it doesn't exists.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.SCHEMA WHERE NAME = 'CBS')
    CREATE SCHEMA 'CBS';
```

How to do this in Snowflake?

Comment: Obviously you’ve read the Snowflake documentation so can you show what you’ve tried and what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the 'if not exists' syntax:

```
Create schema if not exists 'cbs';
```

Comment: If the user's primary role lacks privileges to create schemas in the database, this code returns an error. It's therefore not a great way to check if a schema exists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Matillion ETL to do this in Snowflake, in which case you have two main choices:

1. Use the GUI, under Environments / *choose one* / Right-click / Create Schema

[image: Add schema via UI]

This method will simply fail with an error message if the schema already exists

2. Use an Orchestration [SQL Script component](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2107012), with the SQL that peterb suggested

[image]

You can [parameterize](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2037630) the schema name in the SQL script if you want to avoid hardcoding.